# Setting views and view engine properly to use Reactjs in the frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, view

How do I set the `views`and `view engine` properly in order to write my frontend with Reactjs?

I'm using nodejs with express, and I want to use React in the frontend and not `ejs` or `pug`. Do I have to set up anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks you should research about server side rendering and nextjs

https://nextjs.org/features/server-side-rendering